# generic [T.Generator.Element] initializer

Tags: swift

I'm trying to learn `Swift` and working through the examples in Ch. 1 of Apple's book. The last exercise gives me a lot of headaches, I am trying to construct a function that returns the common elements of two sequences passed as parameters. Here is the code I tried:

```
func anyCommonElements <T, U where T: SequenceType, U: SequenceType, T.Generator.Element: 
Equatable, T.Generator.Element == U.Generator.Element>
    (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> [T.Generator.Element] {
        var result : [T.Generator.Element] // how to default-initialize it?
        for lhsItem in lhs {
            for rhsItem in rhs {
                if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                    result.append(lhsItem)
                }
            }
        }
        return result
}
```

My only problem is that I don't know how to initialize `result` (of type `[T.Generator.Element]`), and I cannot therefore use it latter to append the common elements into it. I tried the obvious

```
var result : [T.Generator.Element] = [T.Generator.Element]()
```

however I'm getting the error `Could not find member Element`, and if I try

```
var result : [T.Generator.Element] = [T.Generator.Element()]()
```

the compiler spits `T.Generator.Element cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

Any idea how to initialize such an array? Or is there any other obvious solution (which I'm not seeing now)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an empty array (or dictionary) without calling the initializer of its element type:

```
var result : [T.Generator.Element] = []
```

(For an empty dictionary, use `[:]`.)

However, it seems like your first try (`[T.Generator.Element]()`) should be acceptable to the compiler -- that doesn't call the element type's initializer. I'd recommend [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) and asking on [the developer forums](http://devforums.apple.com) to see what the official Apple answer is.

Comment: Thanks! Still not familiar with the syntax, I'm still too tied to `C++`, and now realized that probably arrays in `Swift` are just pointers to elements, so you don't need to specify a constructor at creation. What exactly does `[some_type]()` do then?

Comment: If you watch the Swift talks from [WWDC](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos) you'll see that arrays are a bit more than that. As for being too tied to C++, well... they say the first step is admitting the problem, so you're on the right track. ;)